# subsetting a data frame based on a condition of one column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, apply

I have a big data frame. I want to make a subset based on the condition of the values of one column. Say:

`a<-data.frame(x=rep(1:5,5),y=rnorm(25),z=runif(25))`

I want to make a subset based on the values of column `x`. For instance taking values of `x=c(2,3,5)` and create another dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `%in%`

```
a1 <- a[a$x %in% x,]
```

For subsetting only the column 'x'

```
a1 <- a[a$x %in% x, "x", drop=FALSE]
```

If we need to subset the column 'x' to create a `vector` based on the `x` vector

```
v1 <- a$x[a$x %in% x]
```

Comment: Do we create another vector? Say x=c(2,3,5)

Comment: @G1124E  I understand the question as subsetting 'a' based on the values in the `x` vector

Comment: yes.  I want to have another df based on the values on the column x. For example in the above df `a`, take only values of column x which is equal to  2,3 and 5.

Comment: @G1124E  That is what the first one did.  If you need only the column 'x' `a1 <- a[a$x %in% x,'x', drop= FALSE]`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  I am not sure about the expected output.  It could be just the column 'x'.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @akrun. Got it.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `subset`:

```
filter <- c(2,5)
subset(a, x %in% filter)
```

Or equivalently:

```
subset(a, match(x, filter, nomatch = 0)>0)
```

Or

```
a[match(a$x, filter, nomatch = 0)>0,]

   # x           y         z
# 2  2  0.76230930 0.9704342
# 5  5 -1.61846247 0.5786633
# 7  2  0.94024182 0.2805524
# 10 5 -0.08851427 0.6426568
# 12 2  0.78745436 0.1129637
# 15 5 -2.41274754 0.4826690
# 17 2 -0.37616238 0.9518877
# 20 5  1.18745381 0.8110062
# 22 2  0.03233245 0.4599623
# 25 5 -2.28360189 0.4836900
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the value matching function `%in%` and the `filter` verb in the `dplyr` package (a great package for data manipulation).

```
library(dplyr)
a1 <- data.frame(x = rep(1:5,5), y=rnorm(25), z=runif(25))
a2 <- filter(a1, x %in% c(2,3,5))

> a2
   x           y         z
1  2  0.28184946 0.3564756
2  3  0.05634123 0.9826746
3  5 -0.58611510 0.8119334
4  2  0.45211282 0.6267487
5  3 -0.64741961 0.7600619
6  5 -0.28781978 0.3216957
7  2  0.51440342 0.5165707
8  3  1.41958340 0.2328647
9  5 -0.27751501 0.5400576
10 2 -0.74835287 0.7976089
11 3  2.42364991 0.4141980
12 5  0.22175161 0.1051387
13 2  1.54876157 0.6408956
14 3  0.54940989 0.3968186
15 5 -1.16333440 0.9359615
```